# String resources in python (google app engine)

Tags: google-app-engine

How does one work with string resources in python/gae in eclipse+pydev environment? looking for something that is the equivalent of this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xhwfctz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). Also, what is the recommended approach for working with large strings? Create a text file as part of your app and use file I/O, or something else?

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578908/how-do-you-define-config-variables-constants-in-google-app-engine-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "string resource" is a fancy name for text-file, you have three choices;

- If your large text file is *read only* then you can bundle it along with your other application files and access it as you would normally (via `open()` or similar method).
- If your application needs to write lots of text-data then you will have to store it in the datastore using a [TextProperty](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#TextProperty) but beware there are limits on the amoount of data that can be written to the datastore in one go (currently 1MB) ... OR...
- Use the Blobstore API to read/write files

Answer (score 2):

for those still seeking a solution for string resources file on GAE and Python (2.7), I used a YAML formated file:

1. create a file named "strings.txt" (for example), it's content can be something like this:

   ```
   level_1_name: this is a text

   # this is a comment
   test:
   - testtitle: test title
     testtitlechild: testtitlechild
   ```
2. place this on the bottom of your main application file:

   ```
   # strings file (YAML format) initialization
   strings = yaml.load(open("strings.txt", "r"))
   ```
3. then you get 'strings' as dict, using it goes as follows:

   ```
   strings["level_1_name"]
   ```